# Cypress - check test failure in global afterEach

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

Is there a possibility to check in global `afterEach` if test (`it`) failed?

Such global `afterEach` is located in `support/index.js`:

```
afterEach(() => {
  // check if test failed and perform some actions
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `afterEach` hook and remain in the scope of the Cypress context (where `cy` commands are available), for example:

```
afterEach(function() {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/15047

Or you can use `test:after:run` event and switch to `node` context (where any kind of node code can be executed outside of the scope of Cypress, like accessing database or file system), for example:

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
    if (test.state === 'failed') {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Cypress-Events

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is the after:spec and is exposed via plug-ins. You'll have access to the spec and the results.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-spec-api#Syntax

Comment: You can't call any `cy` commands within these events, so they're somewhat useless depending on what you're trying to do (for example, taking a full-page screenshot of the failed test).

Comment: True and we don't know exactly what OP is looking to do within the global afterEach().

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, however I figured out this solution:

```
  afterEach(() => {
    if(Cypress.state().test.state !== 'passed') {
      cy.task('log', "Test did not pass: " + Cypress.state().test.title);
    }
  });
```

Advantage of above solution is that you can use `cy.task(..)` unlike:

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
    if (test.state === 'failed') {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Which can't use `task`.